# jQuery UI + Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, tabs, haml

I have the following code in a haml file on my site:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "web-app-theme/base2", "web-app-theme/themes/activo/style", "web-app-theme/override", 'web-app-theme/tabs'
= javascript_include_tag 'tabber.js', 'jquery-1.3.2.min.js', 'jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js'
:javascript
  $(function() {

    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

    $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){

      var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

      if (i != totalSize) {
          next = i + 2;
          $(this).append("Next Page »");
      }

      if (i != 0) {
          prev = i;
          $(this).append("« Prev Page");
      }

    });

    $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() { 
             $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
             return false;
         });


  });
#page-wrap
  #tabs
    %ul
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-1"} 1
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-2"} 2
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-3"} 3
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-4"} 4
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-5"} 5
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-6"} 6
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-7"} 7
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-8"} 8
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-9"} 9
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-10"} 10
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-11"} 11
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-12"} 12
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-13"} 13
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-14"} 14
      %li
        %a{:href => "#fragment-15"} 15
    #fragment-1.ui-tabs-panel
      %p Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    #fragment-2.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
      %p Donec ultricies senectus tristique egestas vitae, et ac morbi habitant quam sit mi quam, malesuada leo. Vestibulum tempor Mauris tortor libero eget, egestas. eu vitae feugiat netus amet Pellentesque ante. amet, ultricies eleifend turpis sit placerat et semper. Aenean est. fames
    #fragment-3.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
      %p ante. Mauris Vestibulum est. fames egestas quam, leo. amet tristique sit libero egestas. ultricies mi turpis senectus Pellentesque habitant eu ac morbi netus eget, Aenean malesuada vitae, semper. eleifend et feugiat vitae amet, placerat Donec et tortor ultricies tempor quam sit
    #fragment-4.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-5.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-6.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-7.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-8.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-9.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-10.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-11.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-12.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-13.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-14.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
    #fragment-15.ui-tabs-panel.ui-tabs-hide
      %p The end.
```

The code is fine in that it creates the correct tab interface, however the buttons do not work, they just appear as text, so I was wondering if there is something I am supposed to do to make the javascript work properly? I tried removing the javascript code in the haml file and putting it in application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
$(function() {

var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

$    (".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){

  var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

  if (i != totalSize) {
      next = i + 2;
      $(this).append("Next Page »");
  }

  if (i != 0) {
      prev = i;
      $(this).append("« Prev Page");
  }

});

$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() { 
         $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
         return false;
     });


});
```

This only caused the tab layout to break and no longer function properly.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that the original code from the jquery site was all in html - and when it converted to haml, it also removed the html from the javascript section. Which then breaks the javascript links from properly working. Lesson learned don't run javascript through haml2html.